# Login a user only if the status = '1' in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authorization

I am working with laravel 5.2 and i want to login the user if the status is active

```
Route::get('/ProductInquiry', function(){ 
      $id = session('esysid');
      $user = UsersModel::where('employeeID', 'LIKE', $id)->get();
      session(['name' => $user[0]->sAMAccountName]);
      return view('home'); 
})->name('home');
```

I have status column in my database and I need help to authenticate the active users by getting the user's status here in routes, so I can know who are the active users of the system. I expect to login the users which have a status = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Laravel `Where` Clause the achieve your result

```
Route::get('/ProductInquiry', function(){ 
      $id = session('esysid');
      $userDetail = UsersModel::where('employeeID', $id)->where('status', 1)->first();
      session(['name' => $userDetail->sAMAccountName]);
      return view('home'); 
})->name('home');
```

Also, As the employeeID is unique so you can use `first` in place of `get` method.

> get() - Return a collection.
>
> first() - Return a single object.

Comment: Hi Ankur Tiwari, I also get the same error when I apply the code :ErrorException in routes.php line 38:
Trying to get property 'sAMAccountName' of non-object

Comment: employeeID unique for all user? Because currently, you are using `Like`. Instead of `Like` you can directly pass `$id` in your `where` clause

Comment: Check the updated code, Make sure the employeeID that you want is exist in DB.

Comment: Thank youuuuuu so much!!!It's working now, i can now login the user which has a status = 1 :) and the status which has a status = '0'  access is now denied. Thank you Ankur Tiwari! :)

Comment: Great @NikNik16, Keep Coding :)

Comment: @NikNik16 Please accept the answer, So it will be helpful for those how has same  kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Route::get('/ProductInquiry', function(){ 
    $id = session('esysid');
    $user = UsersModel::where('employeeID', $id)->whereStatus(1)->first();
    session(['name' => $user->sAMAccountName]);
    return view('home'); 
})->name('home');
```

Comment: Hi Abolfazl Mohajeri, I'm getting the: ErrorException in routes.php line 38:
Trying to get property 'sAMAccountName' of non-object

Comment: try to dd($user) to make sure its not null and is an object that contains sAMAccountName

Comment: It's now working! thank you guys for the help, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink about checking user informations

```
$user = UsersModel::where('status', 1)->find($id)->get();
```

or

```
$user = UsersModel::whereStatus(1)->find($id)->get();
```

Comment: Hi MuhittinCokelek, I encountered  an error: 
QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e_base_201.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `e_base_201` where `status` = 1 and `e_base_201`.`id` = WIZ-17-009 limit 1)

Comment: @MuhittinCokelek Please check the description of `find` function of laravel.

Comment: you can add protected $privateKey = "employeeID"; in your UsersModel ( i guessed that your primary key is not id

Comment: I got confused, sorry my primary key is idCount which counts all the user in the table.

Comment: It's now working! thank you guys for the help, I really do appreciate it.